# Java web application node integration issue

Tags: spring, node.js, jquery, rest, express

I am having a web application which is sending a request to my node.js. Node module is calling my Spring REST module. 
**My web application to node call is as below**

```
$.ajax({ 
        type : "POST", 
        url : "http://localhost:9090/module", 
        dataType : 'json', 
        data : msgDetails, 
        xhrFields : { withCredentials : true }, 
        success : function(data) {
        console.log("getInbox" + JSON.stringify(data.message));
  }, error : function(data) {
        alert("Error in the AJAX response." + data);
  } });
```

**my node is as below**

```
var express = require("express"), 
app = express(), 
http = require("http").createServer(app);

var requestObj = require('request');  
responseBody = "";
indexresponseBody = null;
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/module', function(req, res){
    var tempInbox = "";
    var tmp = req;
    var authKey = req.body.pubKey;
    var reqBody = req.body;
    console.log("POST"+" - "+JSON.stringify(reqBody)+" - "+authKey);
    restCMCall("http://ip:port/restmodule/controller/call", req, res,authKey,reqBody);
    //res.end(JSON.stringify(body));
    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    //resp.header('Charset', 'utf-8');
    res.send({"name1":"name"});
});


function restCMCall(resturl, req, res, authKey,reqBody){
var i = 0;
console.log("reqBody :- "+reqBody+" resturl "+resturl+" "+i++);
requestObj({
    url : resturl,
    method : "POST",
    headers : { "Content-Type" : "application/json","pubKey":authKey},
    body : JSON.stringify(reqBody)
},
function (error, resp, body) {
    tempInbox = body;
    console.log(resp+" inbox body :- "+"   -------- "+i++);
    //resp.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'application/json','charset':'UTF-8'});
    //res.write(JSON.stringify({"hello":"xxx"}));  
    //res.end(JSON.stringify(body));
    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    //resp.header('Charset', 'utf-8');
    res.send(body);
}
);
    console.log(i++);
}
```

Till now I am able to get the response from the spring module and is able to print on node console. But when I am trying to add this response in response of request made by web application then it is not sent.

In Firefox Browser firebug it shows as

```
Response Headers
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  21
Content-Type    application/json
Date    Mon, 07 Oct 2013 16:13:38 GMT
X-Powered-By    Express
```

but response tab as blank.

I am using express module to call spring rest web service calls node.js.

Please let me know if I am missing anything. I have also tried using

```
response.json(body)
```

But this is also not working.

Comment: Both web application and REST application are deployed on tomcat server on same machine and my node application is running on some another machine/server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be making the request to `url : "http://localhost:9090/getInbox"` because you have not created an endpoint in your Node app that matches `POST: /module`

Comment: yes I am making request to http://localhost:9090/module in node module. Please find updated post.